# It is required to implement licensing APIs for paid app?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I have done an uwp app for Windows Store. It has no trial period or in-app purchases. I can't find any docs that make me clear if there is required to implement licensing check to avoid illegal copies or if Windows Store app does it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want normal purchases from the store then you can set your price when you publish the app and Windows will handle the rest. See [Set pricing and availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/set-app-pricing-and-availability#pricing) for details. Likewise, if you want a time (but not feature) limited trial then you just set that when you publish the app.

You only need to write custom code if you want custom behavior. For example, if you want to limit features during a trial period or add features based on in-app purchases then you need to write code to do that.